# Office 2019 unhappy with two PCs, one SSD

Tags: windows, ssd, microsoft-office

I want to be able to remove the SSD from my Windows 10 PC and attach it to another Windows 10 PC, but not have Office 2019 get upset.

To clarify:

- I own both PCs
- all software is fully licensed (Windows 10, Office 2019, etc)

**To explain my scenario**, I have two locations of work, but in two different countries. I need to take all of my data/information with me when I board a plane and fly to my alternative location and be able to minimise the amount of downtime whilst establishing the new office. As I could be in either location for weeks/months at a time, the hassle/inconvenience of updates is not an option, nor unfortunately is Cloud storage.

Ultimately, all of my data is held on an SSD (and obviously backed up) and I want to move this SSD between locations, reattach and continue as if nothing was a problem.

So, I currently have a powerful desktop PC in each location but each PC lacks a bootable drive (and which cannot/will not be used in my absence). Through the use of external SSD docks, I can have all of my information from my SSD available instantly when I reconnect the SSD to the new PC, but without the weight (and cost!) of carrying a physical computer, such as a laptop, onto an aeroplane. (Indeed, laptops are very lightweight and portable, but the weight vs power is not an option for me and my situation.)

Upon my arrival at my other office, the newly attached the SSD into my PC for the first time in months, and the computer boots as normal, and my work pattern is not interrupted.

**The problem that I am having**, is that Office 2019 does not like this method of work and seems to immediately suspect foul play, to the extent that it requires the license key to be re-entered.

Whilst this sounds relatively painless, the reality is not as straight forward it ought to be, and has resulted several times between journeys, in the need to completely uninstall Office 2019, and reinstall from scratch. As this is taking a considerable amount of time, I want to resolve this Office licensing issue.

I have purchased a volume license agreement for Office, allowing for 5x installations of Office onto (essentially) five separate computers, potentially for five different users.

I want to be able to use Office on each of my two PCs, as described above, but cannot due to the problems with the Office installation rules.  I have investigated alternative brands of Office-like tools, but I want to use the products that I have paid substantially for.

Should this be able to work in the manner I want? Is there technical reason that this is not possible?

Comment: Office 2019 is generally a stand alone, single user license. For what you are trying to do, I suggest a subscription to Office 365. This a a better and more flexible product for what you are trying to do. It licenses via the Microsoft licensing server on the internet.

Comment: Why not cloud storage? It seems made for the job. Windows has always been intransigent on swapping drives between machines. A rather expensive alternative would be two Macs, which would let you do this without blinking. Assuming you set the T2 security accordingly [on newer Macs], you could boot from a portable external on either machine & it would be as though you'd taken the entire computer with you, seamlessly.

Comment: As John said, Office 2019 is different with Microsoft 365 apps, it is only allowed to be installed on one computer, If you need to migrated Office 2019 to another machine, you should uninstalled Office 2019 from previous computer.